# xCode - UIButton showing other ViewController doesn't trigger ViewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm having some problems trying to make a UIButton showing a different ViewController. On my 'menu'-ViewController I have two buttons both showing the 'game'-ViewController. The strange thing is, one of them does work like desired, while the other one doesn't.
It opens the ViewController but the ViewDidLoad() function is not being triggered by the second button.
I have tried deleting the first (working) button to see if only one is able to function in a ViewController.

My question is, is there any setting to a UIButton that could result in this behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Merijn

Comment: The destination view controller is the same in both cases? Show the view controller creation and view loading code

Comment: @Wain yes they are.. they trigger the exact same thing

Comment: So you'll need to show that code

Comment: To answer your question, no, there is no setting for UIButton that could cause this behavior. You need to post the buttons' action method(s).

Comment: @rdelmar there is no code involved.. they are simply linked like this: http://i57.tinypic.com/k4f0nn.png

Comment: I don't see anything useful in that link.

Comment: Depending on how the view is loaded,  `viewDidLoad` may not be called again. Per docs, "This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory." If it is not unloaded, this method will not be called again. If you are looking for a method that fires every time, you should use `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @rdelmar the image is a bit small.. it doesn't really stand out in the page.

Comment: @rmp  guess I'll just have to do more testing and hope I come across something unusual... Thanks for all the help!